# TCL_REGEXP:: How to grep a line from variable that looks similar in TCL

Tags: regex, tcl

My TCL script:

```
set test {
a for apple
b for ball
c for cat
number n1
numbers 2,3,4,5,6
d for doctor
e for egg
number n2
numbers 56,4,5,5
}

set lines [split $test \n] 
set data [join $lines :]
if { [regexp {number n1.*(numbers .*)} $data x y]} {
    puts "numbers are : $y"
}
```

Current output if I run the above script:

```
C:\Documents and Settings\Owner\Desktop>tclsh stack.tcl
numbers are : numbers 56,4,5,5:

C:\Documents and Settings\Owner\Desktop>
```

Expected output:

In the script regexp, If I specify "number n1"... Its should print  "numbers are : numbers 2,3,4,5,6"
    If I specify "number n2"... Its should print  "numbers are : numbers 56,4,5,5:"

Now always its prints the last (final line - numbers 56,4,5,5:) as output. How to resolve this issue.

Thanks,

Kumar

Comment: The output is that way because that's what you ask for: the string `numbers` followed by zero or more characters, on the condition that the string `n1` followed by zero or more characters comes before it. You might want to look at the term "greedy match". A solution that doesn't use a regular expression will be a lot easier to write, try that first.

Comment: I need to achieve this by using regexp. This is my project rule :). Any way to achieve this by using regexp?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using

```
regexp {number n1.*?(numbers .*)\n} $test x y
```

(note that I'm matching against `test`. There is no need to replace the newlines.)

There are two differences from your pattern.

1. The question mark behind the first star makes the match *non-greedy*.
2. There is a newline character behind the capturing parentheses.

Your pattern told `regexp` to match from the first occurrence of `number n1` up to the last occurrence of `numbers`, and it did. This is because the `.*` match between them was *greedy*, i.e. it matched as many characters as it could, which meant it went past the first `numbers`.

Making the match non-greedy means that the pattern will match from the first occurrence of `number n1` up to the following occurrence of `numbers`, which was what you wanted.

After `numbers`, there is another `.*` match which is a bit troublesome. If it were greedy, it would match everything up to the end of the variable content. If it were non-greedy, it wouldn't match *any* characters, since matching a zero-length string satisfies the match. Another problem is that the Tcl RE engine doesn't really allow for switching back from non-greedy mode.

You can fix this by forcing the pattern to match one character past the text that you want the `.*` to match, making the zero-length match invalid. Matching a newline (`\n`) or space (`\s`) character should work. (This of course means that there *must* be a newline / other space character after every data field: if a numbers field is the last character range in the variable that field can't be located.)

Documentation: [regular expression syntax](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/re_syntax.htm), [regexp](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/regexp.htm)

Answer (score 0):

To use a Tcl variable in a regular expression is easy. On one level anyway: you put the regular expression in double quotes so that you have standard Tcl variable substitution inside it *prior* to it being passed to the RE engine:

```
# ...
set target "n1"
if { [regexp "number $target.*(numbers .*)" $data x y]} {
    # ...
```

The hard part is that you've got to remember that switching to `"`…`"` from `{`…`}` will affect the *whole* of that word, and that the substitutions are of regular expression fragments. We usually recommend using `{`…`}` because that's easier to get consistently and unconfusingly right in the majority of cases.

Let's illustrate how this can get annoying. In your specific case, you *may* want to actually use this:

```
if { [regexp "number $target\[^:\]*:(numbers \[^:\]*)" $data x y]} {
```

The character sets here exclude the `:` (which you've — unnecessarily — used as a newline replacement) but because `[`…`]` is *also* standard Tcl metasyntax, you have to backslash-quote it. (Things get *even more* annoying when you want to always use the contents of the variable as a literal even though they might include RE metasyntax characters; you need a `regsub` call to tidy things up. And you start to potentially make Tcl's RE cache less efficient too.)